# Render Problem "Path.op() not supported" in latest material design version

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx, material-components-android

I'm using below with *androidx* in *Android studio 3.5.3*:

1. androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
2. com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

My gradle is as below:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02'
...
mindSdkVersion 26
compileSdkVersion 29
targetSdkVersion 29
```

### Problems

In the editor of Android studio,I have this:

> render Problem Path.op() not supported

The app still can run without problem.
But do I have to be concerned about this kind of error message when uploading to play store?

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

Comment: does anyone have this problem or this is just me? does this problem will cause any issue ?

Comment: The red dot or the exclaimation mark on the top right corner in editor

Answer (score 8):

Use new layout rendering engine.
For this, go to *Settings*  *Experimental*  Check *Use new Layout Rendering Engine*.

If this did not work alone, also change:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-beta01'
```

This should work.