# OnActivityResult override nothing occured when using paypal sdk

Tags: android, kotlin, paypal, paypal-android-sdk

I m trying to build an ecommerce app using paypal-android-sdk. I have tried the sdk version: 2.14.2, 2.15.3, 2.16.0  for Android studio version 3.5.3
The result is the same and it show the above message: onActivityResult overrides nothing.
I did add ? after Intent. what is the problem? Can someone help me on this? appreciate your help.
below is the code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pay_pal_payment)

        config = PayPalConfiguration().environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
            .clientId(ShoppingCart.client_id)

        var i = Intent(this, PayPalService::class.java)
        i.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config)
        startService(i)


        val total_amt:String = intent.getStringExtra("TTL")
        Payment_tv_TotalAmount.setText(total_amt)

        Payment_btnPay.setOnClickListener {

            amount = Payment_tv_TotalAmount.text.toString().toDouble()

            var payment = PayPalPayment(BigDecimal.valueOf(amount),"USD","My Pal", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE) 

            var intent = Intent(this, PaymentActivity::class.java ) 

            intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config)
            intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment)

            startActivityForResult(intent,my_request_code)

        }
    }



 override fun OnActivityResult(requestCode:Int, resultCode:Int, data:Intent?) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if(requestCode == my_request_code){

              if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                var i = Intent(this, PaymentConfirmActivity::class.java)

                startActivity(i)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: try playing around the nullability of the parameters

Comment: can you show me what to do? my code is what I did.  I did add ? on intent. Nothing work

Comment: what is the parent  of your activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method name should be `onActivityResult` not `OnActivityResult`

the first letter is a lower case character.

Comment: Can I ask you a question. Is Paypal-android-Sdk  deprecated? can it still be used to get payment? Thanks

Comment: yes, the error is gone now. But I dont know it will work?

Comment: the documentation does say its deprecated so I don't think you should go ahead and use it, please see https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK

Comment: BUT in other github the doc says you still can use it but it will not be updated, so you should migrate to BrainTree. This is like yes, you can use the old one, but try to use the new braintree api. is this correct? well ,it will be kind if you can advise. Anyway Ijust want to be sure. Thanks

Comment: they want to give time for people to migrate so its not good for new projects to use it. Check out their alternatives

Comment: Do you mind to help me another problem. The Activity can be rendered or displayed but I see an Exclaimation mark on the editor.  I just dont figure out. here the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060759/render-problem-path-op-not-supported-in-latest-material-design-version